# Cuckoo sandbox: shows "Configuration details about machine windows_7 are missing" error

Tags: python, testing, analysis, cuckoo

I have installed cuckoo sandbox in ubuntu environment with windows7 32 bit as guest os. I have followed the instructions given in their website.The vm is named windows_7. I have edited the "machine" and "label" field properly in "virtualbox.conf".

But when I try to start the cuckoo executing "sudo python cuckoo.py" it gives me an error :

"WARNING: Configuration details about machine windows_7 are missing: Option windows_7 is not found in configuration, error: Config instance has no attribute 'windows_7'

CRITICAL: CuckooCriticalError: No machines available.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue just by changing the configuration file "virtualbox.conf". in this configuration file it says that the virtual machine as [cuckoo1] (title of the virtual machine configuration).

Since my virtual machine name is "windows_7" i have to change `[cuckoo1]` to `windows_7`. That is why cuckoo don't get the virtual machine configuration (because configurations by default is set for `[cuckoo1]` virtual machine name).